# react-native-hms-maps map is blank

Tags: javascript, react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have a react native app that I am currently trying to make compliant with Huawei's HMS APK so that users with Mate 30 or P40 devices can use our app.

I have removed react-native-maps for this release and I have replaced it with react-native-hms-maps by following the instructions found in the Huawei HMS Core Developer Guides for React-Native.

When I run the app, and I navigate to the screen where I am rendering the map, only a blank page shows. Upon running the app with the logcats running, I was able to pin point this error in the logs:

```
2020-09-01 23:23:27 23608-23608/? I/MapRender: ERROR MapView.cpp:296: MapView::[SwitchMapType] enter!
```

I don't know if this is related to my problem.

My react-native code looks like this:

```
import HMSMap from 'react-native-hms-map';

...other code....

render = () => {
  const address = this.state.address;

  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <HMSMap
      style={styles.map}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude:  -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta:  0.0922,
        longitudeDelta:  0.0421,
      }}
    />
   </View>
  );
 };
```

And my style object looks like this:

```
 container: {
  ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  alignItems: 'center',
  borderColor: 'black',
  borderWidth: 2
 },
 map: {
  ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
 }
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong ?

Comment: As we can see ERROR MapView.cpp:296, the current plug-in does not have C++ plug-ins. So this error is not necessarily related to the blank map issue. Could you please give a more complete log? Currently, the content of this error is insufficient. To analyze this error, the Map Kit is required.

Comment: I've added the Map Kit - the android logs are pretty dense so it is proving very difficult to pinpoint the exact error

Comment: You can add pictures in the question if the logs are dense. :)

Comment: We checked the the log screenshots you provided [here](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0202344452519970119&fid=0101187876626530001).  It is irrelevant to the map issue. Please send the full log to hmscore@huawei.com. If you have more questions, feel free to contact me!

Comment: I logged onto the Huawei Developer Console to read the developer guides again and it seems that the entire React Native section has now been removed ? Are you aware of this ?

Comment: Maybe you are visiting the old version of website. Here is the link: [Neact Native Map Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/introduction-0000001050143001)

Comment: The steps have been updated since I checked yesterday. I have followed the new steps and the map shows now

Comment: Great. Here is our [Development Documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development) page, to find the documents you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old version of React Native Map Plugin 4.0.2, and it will be placed offline after July 30, 2020, which causes this issue.

A note is added on “[Version Change History](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050141050)” part on documentation, please kindly refer to it.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer the article [HMS Map Kit Elucidated : Using React Native](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201267509735820036&fid=0101187876626530001) to know about how to integrate HMS Map in React Native.